# Angular Load component list from json file

Tags: angular, angular13

I am using Angular 13 and I'm looking for a way to have a list or components load by reading the component names from a json file.

For example..I have a json file with the names of the components that I want to load into my app.component.html

```
componentListToLoad = [
  {
    "name": "Component1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Component2"
  }
]
```

Then in a for loop I would get the two components loaded.

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let list of componentListToLoad">
  // Load the component list
</div>
```

How can I do this in Angular?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In app.component.ts file declare componentListToLoad array

```
  let componentListToLoad:any = [
  {
    "name": "Component1"
   },
  {
   "name": "Component2"
   }
  ];
```

In app.component.html file add following code

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let list of componentListToLoad">
    <div>{{ list.name }}</div>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: and the list can change at runtime if needed?

Comment: i can't understand what you say

Comment: Your code is not loading an Angular component...just the value of a json object. I need to load a component

Comment: Unless you know how to change this: componentListToLoad:any = [
  {
    "name": "Component1"
   },
  {
   "name": "Component2"
   }
  ]; to this: componentListToLoad:any = [
  {
    "name": Component1
   },
  {
   "name": Component2
   }
  ];